# Windows CE Emulator related error when using VS.NET 2005 and 2008

Tags: windows-ce, fatal-error

I have a situation where i need to debug a Windows CE application in both Vs.NET 2008 as well as VS.NET 2005.

After I switch between the emulators in these 2 environments a few times, i get the error:

> A fatal error has occurred and debugging needs to be terminated. HRESULT=0x8013110e. Error code=0x0.

Why should it happen only after switching back and forth? The task manager shows sufficient memory and I am not able to debug this.

What could be the problem ?

Regards,
Chak

Comment: Can u tell me how to make visual stdio recognize the installed emulator in devices section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wager that this has something to do with both development environments being installed at once. You can install multiple Visual Studio dated versions at once, but they have to be installed in date order. Perhaps the 2008 emulator package was conflicting with 2005?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with these emulators if you have [PAE installed](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/891667) on XP, certainly more than suggested in the linked MS tech note.  Try disabling PAE and see if it cures your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks . We tried this. However, when we deploy the application on the VS.NET 2005 it does so, but when the same is done VS.NET 2008 app, it fails to load in the emulator. So there seems to be some corruption of shared resources.

If we uninstall 2005 and work only in 2008 it works.

Thanks,
Chak.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe but we just put the two installations on two different boxes, before i read your mail. Maybe that was it.

Thanks.